# Can you use Adjective + たって?

Tags: grammar

I've got a question regarding the use of the structure ~たって which I've just recently stumbled across.

From what I know so far, this is used in the form Verb(neg) + たって, for example:

> 現金なくたって、カードで支払える。

In its use, it is similar to ~ても：

> 現金なくても、カードで支払える。("Even if you don't have cash, you can pay by card")

My question is:
As the structure ~ても can be used also with an adjective preceding it, can you also use Adjective+たって?

For example:

> 天気が悪くても、海の旅行は楽しい。

Can you say:

> **天気が悪くたって、海の旅行は楽しい。**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Negative verb and adjective behave in the same manner conjugation-wise, so you can form it with adjective in analogy of ～なくたって. Your example is correct.

Grammatically you can create ～たって from:

- verbs (positive), *na*-adjectives & copula: ta-form + って

  > 食べたって, 行ったって, 死んだって, 勉強したって, きれいだったって, 子供だったって
- *i*-adjectives, negative verbs/adjectives (nai-form): adverb form (stem + く) + たって

  > 良くたって, 悪くたって, 行かなくたって, きれいじゃなくたって, 子供じゃなくたって

Theoretically you can also make ～たって with polite endings, but they aren't much heard (except for some, e.g. そんなこと言いましたって) since ～たって itself is a quite casual expression.