# Use of って in this question

Tags: jlpt, particle-って

So I'm working my way through a JLPT 2 question and came across this one, in the "stick the parts in the right order" section.

今になって１週間も前になくした ＿＿　＿＿　＿＿　＿＿　っこないよ。

1.　見つかり
2.　探した
3.　財布を
4.　って

The meaning of the sentence as a whole was immediately clear and it's not the order I need an explanation for but the use of って. The correct sentence reads:

今になって１週間も前になくした財布を探した**って**見つかりっこないよ。

I learned that って was used in colloquial speech as a replacement for the quotation marker と. I also half-remember it being used by the speaker to highlight something/someone/a topic that the listener will know. Is this right and, if so, can you use it these ways:

*昨日って、寒かったね。
*田中さんって、パーティに行きますか。
*吉田さん、知らんって言った。

They would all be okay? So in the case of the first and second example, they are also being used to mark the topic (which in this case is something the listener should also already know).

So in the example N2 question, it's being used to mark 財布 as that's the subject of the sentence but also the listener has pre-knowledge of the lost wallet, with the nuance being something like: "(You know) that wallet that I lost..." or "(about) that wallet that I lost..."?

So you could say something like this: "昨日の試合って、雨のために中止になった。　"You know that game I had yesterday..."?

Answer (score 1):

Your three sentences marked with `*` seem perfectly fine to me. But the (た)って in the sentence in question is used for a different purpose. It's a distinct conjunctive meaning "even if ～". It's still informal/colloquial.

See:

- [How to parse ～なくたって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19593/5010)
- [Can you use Adjective + たって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27715/5010)
- [Some questions about って](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18737/5010)

Comment: So with a past tense verb like 探した, it means something akin to "even though I looked... (it's impossible to find)"? In this case it functions the same as ても or でも？

Comment: Yes 探したって and 探しても are interchangeable, but the former is more colloquial and informal. You can translate it as "Even though you look for it" using the *present* tense.