# てしょうがない/てしかた(が)ない, "You shouldn't"

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, forms like 「てしょうがない」 and 「てしかた(が)ない」 means something like "very, extremely" and "can't be helped", like:

> 心配する理由はなかったけど、どうしても不安でしかたなかった: I didn't have any reason to worry, but I couldn't help be uneasy

Then I found this sentence:

> そんな本は読んでも仕方がない

which was translated as "You shouldn't read a book like that", while I translated it as "I can't help reading a book like that"; there is no context, it's an example sentence from a grammar.

I know those form [can also mean](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%95%E6%A7%98%E3%81%8C%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84) "There is no point in doing something", but I'm not sure how to discriminate between those meanings. After reasearching a bit, I thought the difference was in the 「も」: 「てしかたがない」, "I can't help but"; 「てもしかたがない」, "I shouldn't". The again, I just found this sentence:

> こんな酔っぱらいと時間をつぶしたってしょうがない

which to me sounds like "I couldn't help wasting time with such a drunkard", while it was translated as "I shouldn't have wasted time with such a drunkard", without having 「も」. I'm wondering if 「たって」 is a colloquial form for 「ても」: I know some time ago I found such a case, but I can't find it anymore.

I found some questions here about these forms, but nothing addressing this; in my grammar and on the Internet all I can find are the meaning I gave above, with no explanation about the "You shouldn't" meaning. I did find [this](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-te-shou-ga-nai/) page, in which there are examples like 「まだ証明されていないことを考えてみても仕方がないぜ」, translated as "Do not spend thoughts on a matter which has not been proved", which seems to prove my point, since it does have 「も」.

Am I missing something? Am I right in my `「てしかたがない」, "I can't help but"; 「てもしかたがない」, "I shouldn't"` interpretation? Is it just depending on context?

Comment: `I'm wondering if 「たって」 is a colloquial form for 「ても」: I know some time ago I found such a case, but I can't find it anymore.` -- Would these threads be of help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18737/9831 , https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27715/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right. ～てしょうがない/～てしかたない (without も) can mean "(I) can't help but...", and ～て**も**しょうがない/～て**も**しかたない, "(You) shouldn't..."

And you're also right that ～～たって (<た+とて) is a colloquial way of saying ～～ても, "even if".

So these phrases are *literally* like...

- [感情・感覚を表す表現(phrase expressing feeling or emotion)] + て(で) + しかた(が)ない/しょうがない/しようがない (or たまらない/ならない)
  → "I want/feel... + and + nothing can be done about *it* (←the feeling)." → "I can't help feeling..."
- ～て**も**/～た**って** + しかた(が)ない/しょうがない/しようがない
  → "Even if (I/you) do~~, + nothing can be done about *it* (←the situation)." → "There's no point in doing..."

Examples:

> - 心配で仕方なかった。 I couldn't help worrying. / I was really worried.
> - 心配して**も**仕方ない。 There's no point in worrying. / Don't worry.
> - あの本が読みたくてしょうがない。
>     I can't help but want to read that book. / I wanna read that book so bad.
> - そんな本、読んだ**って**しょうがないよ。
>     There's no point in reading a book like that. / You shouldn't read a book like that.

Comment: ～ても仕方がない can also mean "may/might well do..." (≂ ～のも無理はない) eg 「疑われても仕方がない。」

Comment: To discriminate between "Shouldn't" and "Might well do" one has to see the context?

Comment: そうですね。。どちらとも取れる文の場合、最後は文脈で判断するしかないと思います。