# なく after a verb, what are the uses?

Tags: grammar, kanji, verbs, syntax

夕暮れで 二人 少しずつ**見えなくなっていって** 
In this case I suppose it 見えなく(invisible) + 成っていって（becoming）.

But in this case below how would it work?

> サヨナラ **会えなくなったって** 僕らは続きがあるから

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. The usage of なく is the same in both sentences. Are you simply treating 見えなく as a word that means 'invisible' or do you understand why it takes that form? Please provide more details.

Comment: my question is exactly what なく　means. And what なたってI do not undrestand why it takes that form, i wanted an explanation of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 見えなくなっていって

見える dictionary form of verb -- 'to be visible'.

見えない negation of dictionary form -- 'to be not visible'.

見えなく continuative form of 見えない. This form is needed when preceeding なる (to become).

見えなくなる 'to become not visible'. Another example -- 暑い + なる --> 暑くなる = become hot.

なって te-form of なる -- 'become ...'.

なっていって -- なる + te-form of いく -- 'start becoming ...'. See [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B).

見えなくなっていって 'start to become not visible' = 'start to disappear ...'

> my question is exactly what なく　means.

In summary, it's the continuative form of ない which is needed when you want to say that something becomes something. For an i-adjective or ない replace the final い with く and then add なる.

> 会えなくなったって

会う dictionary form of verb -- 'to meet'.

会える potential form -- 'to be able to meet'.

会えない negation of potential form -- 'to be unable to meet'.

会えなくなる just like above -- 'to become unable to meet'.

会えなくなったって ' even if we'll become unable to meet. This 'even if' form is made by converting the verb into past tense and adding って i.e. なる --> なった --> なったって.　See [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/can-you-use-adjective-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6).

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, your understanding is correct. 
In The second example, って　has a different usage than the first. It means "although"

In [This webpage](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6), at the very end, section 4 part 2, it gives a usage of って that is the same as your second example.

（た、だ、からなどに付いて）譲歩を表す。ても、でも。たところで、だとしても

(attached after ta, da, kara etc.) To show compromise. means temo, demo, ta dokoro de, da toshidemo